# One service, two instances, how to configure with ASP.NET Core DI?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

With ASP.NET Core's Options pattern one can create Service and register it with two separate calls.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddTransient<MyService>();

    services.Configure<MyServiceOptions>(o => o.Param = 1);

    services.AddMvc();
};
```

However, I am entirely unclear on how and if it is possible to instantiate two instances of a service and bind different options to them?  i.e. given two specialisations of some base class, how do we share a single options class between them?

```
public class MyService {}

public class MyService1 : MyService {}

public class MyService2 : MyService2 {}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddTransient<MyService1>();
    services.AddTransient<MyService2>();

    // What goes here?
    // config for instance 1
    //services.Configure<MyServiceOptions>(o => o.Param = 1);
    // config for instance 2
    //services.Configure<MyServiceOptions>(o => o.Param = 2);

    services.AddMvc();
};
```

Basically I want something like the IServiceCollection.AddDbContext extension method, but for services, and I've looked at the EF Core extension methods and I don't get them at all.

Comment: Could you make `MyServiceOptions` generic and register it twice as `MyServiceOptions<MyService1>` and `MyServiceOptions<MyService2>`?

Comment: Give each class its own unique options class.

Comment: @Kirk Larkin: That really seems to be the way of it. Ive almost got a DbContext kind of thing working but its sooo complex. There. Surely. Must be an easier way to configure services: This is a lot of boilerplate simply because I don't want hardcoded settings per service.

Answer (score 7):

Going with @Kirk Karkin's advice -

```
public class MyServiceOptions
{
    public int setting { get; set; }
}

public class MyService
{
    public MyService(IOptions<MyServiceOptions> options)
    {
        // TODO: Capture options.
    }
}

public class MyServiceOptions<TMyService> : MyServiceOptions
    where TMyService : MyService
{
}
```

Now I can create instances of this service by extending it:

```
public class MyService1 : MyService
{
    public MyService1(IOptions<MyServiceOptions<MyService1>> options>):base(options) 
    {
    }
 }
```

And then registering multiple instances is easy in Configure Services:

```
services.AddTransient<MyService1>();
services.AddScoped<MyService2>();
services.Configure<MyServiceOptions<MyService1>>(Configuration.GetSection("MyService1Settings"));
services.Configure<MyServiceOptions<MyService2>>(Configuration.GetSection("MyService2Settings"));
```